# why do we add an application.config file for the connection string?? what is the purpose of this file

Tags: c#

i want to know that why do we add an app.config file in c# projects for the connection string if our work is also access able by simple combining the command text and data adapter .. 
what is the functionality of this .xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to change the runtime parameters (things like connection strings, for example if the database gets moved onto a different server) at runtime without having to recompile and re-distribute the application.

Comment: ohkey so when i use my project on any other Computer, i will not be changing the connection string again and again.. is it?

Comment: The connection string must point to the database location, whether that be on the same machine as the application or a different machine. app.config just provides an easy way to modify that connection string without recompiling the application.

Comment: If you work in a multi-environment dev team (Dev, QA, UAT, Staging, Production Environments for example) each of these have different databases.  Having configuration settings in a string based file like app.config/web.config allows us to change the connection string without recompiling for each environment.

Comment: and what if i want to get data in the grid so do i use command text and data adapter?? i mean.. how can i get data from my DB into the grid ? without using the command text and data adapter?

Comment: app.config and the connection string has nothing to do with "without using the command text and data adapter."  I suggest you read up on the SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter, SqlDataReader and SqlCommand classes.  The connection string is what you pass to the SqlConnection, which is required in all cases.  Having it in the app.config just makes management easier.  If you don't have it in app.config, you hard-code it - but you still need the Sql* classes to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

connection string is always required. sometimes it is passed implicitly so you don't notice it. app.config is just a place where they can be stored so you can change them when server name or other parameters change

Answer (score 0):

Having the configuration data (including the Connection string) stored in a separate file form your binary, allows you the freedom to update the values stored in the configuration without having to recompile your application.

This can be great if for instance your application wants to talk to different databases for dev - Test and Production.

You do not have to use the app.config xml structure, its just a convenience that the .net framework provide code to read/update.

You could also store configuration data in your own format, pull it from Active Directory, or a dedicated configuration service.